# Why this org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update occurs only on the remote (virtual) server

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, struts

I am getting this error with my externals server with hibernate. Whilst running my data base locally, the error never occurs. The following is the stack exception:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at fr.action.planning.site.ToCloneVacationAction.execute(ToCloneVacationAction.java:469)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at fr.util.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:37)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at fr.GenericDAO.findById(GenericDAO.java:94)
at fr.dao.SocietyDAO.findSocietyById(SocietyDAO.java:58)
at fr.service.SocietyPeer.getSocietyName(SocietyPeer.java:83)
at fr.service.EmployeePeer.getEmployerName(EmployeePeer.java:219)
at fr.action.employee.BaseEmployeeDisplayAction.createEmployeesBean(BaseEmployeeDisplayAction.java:82)
at fr.action.planning.site.ToCloneVacationAction.execute(ToCloneVacationAction.java:320)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2222)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2118)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2374)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:84)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:243)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:227)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:296)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1008)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
at fr.dao.GenericDAO.findById(GenericDAO.java:87)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1124)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:676)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1166)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1067)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2208)
... 42 more


javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at fr.planning.site.ToCloneVacationAction.execute(ToCloneVacationAction.java:469)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at fr.util.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:37)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at fr.dao.GenericDAO.findById(GenericDAO.java:94)
at fr.dao.SocietyDAO.findSocietyById(SocietyDAO.java:58)
at fr.service.SocietyPeer.getSocietyName(SocietyPeer.java:83)
at fr.service.EmployeePeer.getEmployerName(EmployeePeer.java:219)
at fr.action.employee.BaseEmployeeDisplayAction.createEmployeesBean(BaseEmployeeDisplayAction.java:82)
at fr.action.planning.site.ToCloneVacationAction.execute(ToCloneVacationAction.java:320)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2222)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2118)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2374)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:84)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:243)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:227)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:296)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1008)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
at fr.dao.GenericDAO.findById(GenericDAO.java:87)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1124)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:676)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1166)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1067)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2208)
... 42 more
java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at fr.dao.GenericDAO.findById(GenericDAO.java:94)
at fr.dao.SocietyDAO.findSocietyById(SocietyDAO.java:58)
at fr.service.SocietyPeer.getSocietyName(SocietyPeer.java:83)
at fr.service.EmployeePeer.getEmployerName(EmployeePeer.java:219)
at fr.action.employee.BaseEmployeeDisplayAction.createEmployeesBean(BaseEmployeeDisplayAction.java:82)
at fr.action.planning.site.ToCloneVacationAction.execute(ToCloneVacationAction.java:320)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at fr.util.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:37)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [fr.model.employee.Employee#510]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2222)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2118)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2374)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:84)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:243)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:227)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:296)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1008)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
at fr.dao.GenericDAO.findById(GenericDAO.java:87)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1124)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:676)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1166)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1067)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2208)
... 42 more
```

I do not think code is the issue as the code worked fine with previous servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at first glance it seems like a MySql error rather than a Hibernate one.

If the external DB is of different version than your local, it might be because of [this MySql bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61225).

Comment: I think you're right. I'm currently looking for 5.5 PPAs for ubuntu 10.10 and 11.10

Answer (score 0):

it might a permission problem, check with your database credentials (configuration). because same code is working in local and not working in remote means, it might be a database configuration or permission problem, so check those areas.

Comment: I thought it might be but I doubt it. The user access is root, the configuration is as installed by default.